Дозагрузка изображений
вобщем пишу я сайт для поиска обой на пк, и возникла задача реализовать аллгоритм, который будет прогружать картинки( взятые с яндекс диска) по мере просмотра пользователем страницы. Условно чтобы после открытия страницы отображались сначала первые 30 картинок, после их пролистывания загружались еще 30 и так далее.
Метод отображения я написал на php, вот он:
    // Вывод картинок
    function Update($disk, $wallpapers) {
        if (isset($wallpapers)) {
            foreach ($wallpapers as $wallpaper) {
                $picture = $wallpaper['id'];
                $filename = "/Обои/" . $wallpaper['url'] . ".jpg";
                $namePicture = $wallpapers["name"];
                try {
                    $resource = $disk->getResource($filename);
                    $link = $resource->toArray();
                    $url = $link['sizes'][0]['url'];
                    echo "<a class='walppapers' alt='$namePicture' name='picture' href='picture.php?picture=$picture' ><img src='$url' alt='Изображение'></a>";
                } catch (Exception $ex) {

                }
            }
        } 
    }

Осталось только написать аллгоритм, но как и на каком языке? Может вы подскажете, я знаю лишь то что это проблем не возникло писал бы я проект онли на js, там же и есть метод для отслеживания прокрутки страницы, но как его интегрировать в код php, чтобы они работали бок о бок, я не знаю. Может для этого нужна библиотека какая. Помогите в общем советом.

из js  делаешь ajax запрос на бэк, на бэке делаешь что нужно и возвращаешь данные, на js отображаешь ответ

Решил проблему использовав "ленивую загрузку" (lazy load).

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
